# How to display the count (number of balls) on each sides

Tags: java, swing, timer, paint, keylistener

I wrote a program to play Maxwell's Demon. It should have a window with 2 sides and a few

dots running around bouncing off the walls. There's a wall in the middle. When you click a

button, a gap opens up in the wall (until you unclick). This should allow a person to try

to get more balls on one side than the other. You can display the count on each side.

This is the main class, I have two other classes one is Dot ( where I make my dots move, and

tell how fast), and the other one is BLueDot(where i create the blue dots).

So what I want is that to display the counts of the balls on each sides? Or How many we

got (balls) on each side of the walls?

As suggested by JDeveloper to add count++ to my doMoreDots() method to get the total number

of dots, but it is not giving me any total it is returning 0s.

Main Program

```
package dotChaser;

//DotChaser.java
//This program does some simple animation where a dot move around
//the blue dots.

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DotChaser extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    javax.swing.Timer time; // generates ticks that drive the animation
    protected double deltaT = 0.020; // how much time for each tick
    BlueDot[] blues; // holds the blue dots
    int blueCounter = 0; // number of blue dots
    //Label howMany =  new Label();
    JTextField tf;// The text field for the key listener 
    boolean open; // open= true part. pass through, open = false part. dont pass through

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DotChaser d = new DotChaser();
    }
    // constructor

    public DotChaser() {
        Dot.theDotChaser = this;
        //time managment
        time = new javax.swing.Timer((int) (1000 * deltaT), this);
        time.start();

        blues = new BlueDot[200];


        tf = new JTextField("---------------");
        add(tf);
        tf.addKeyListener(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            blues[blueCounter++] = new BlueDot();

            //count++;                                     
            //howMany.setText(ballReport());

            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            setTitle("Dot Chaser!");
            setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    // the work its doing 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == time) {
            doTime();
        }
        repaint();
    }
    // key listener mouse motion 

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        System.out.println("you pressed key=" + k.getKeyChar());
        open = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
        System.out.println("you released key=" + k.getKeyChar());
        open = false;
    }

    // the clock ticked, so tell all the dots to move a little
    public void doTime() {

        for (int i = 0; i < blueCounter; i++) {
            blues[i].move(deltaT);
        }
    }
    /* Here is what I added from the suggestion */
     // make another blue dot (and add it to the blues array)
     static int count = 0;

    public void doMoreDots() {
        blues[blueCounter++] = new BlueDot();
        count++
        repaint();
    }

    // paint all the dots
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < blueCounter; i++) {
            blues[i].drawMe(g);
        }

        {
            // draw the wall
            g.setColor(Color.pink);
            g.fillRect(250, 40, 90, 200);
            g.fillRect(250, 400, 90, 300);

        }
        // close wall when false
        if (open == false) {
            g.fillRect(250, 200, 90, 200);
            g.fillRect(250, 400, 90, 300);
        }

        System.out.println("count" + count);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(String.format("%d", blueCounter), 510, 640);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use blueCounter?

Comment: How would it work out? because I did blueCounter and it crashed? I mean if there is a way to use it that would be great.

Comment: try replacing `g.drawString("" + count, 510, 640);` with `g.drawString(String.format("%d", blueCounter), 510, 640);`

Comment: It just give number 20 the whole time?

Comment: dont forget to repaint the frame.

Comment: your ActionListener is not registered therefor the actionPreformed method will never trigger and i really cant see how you want to trigger it on a JFrame, since you repaint inside actionPreformed you really never do!

Comment: Oh sorry I see you passed it in to the Timer.

Comment: So um what is wrong now, do I repaint something?

Comment: Well I don't see where do you call doMoreDots. I see the first 20 you add but thats it. so the count should be 20, that seems about right!
can you update the code here?

Comment: Here I just edited it.

Comment: where do you call `doMoreDots()`?

Comment: Oh wait I don't call that method, because I thought it is a void?

Comment: you dont call it because its a void method?

Comment: Sorry wait so I need to call it, where?

Comment: well you can call it inside your `doTime()` method just to see if your problem has been solved and the count is drawn correctly and it updates. but for the program it self its up to you where you call your functions depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Ok so I called it in doTime() and the dots froze and everything crashed.

Comment: I called it in my paint method it start counting very fast all of the dots and not just one side of my wall, and crashed at 200.

Comment: it means that its working, the reason it crashed is becouse your blues array has a length of 200 and when it tried to increment it againp you robably got the indexOutOfBound Exception. but the problem you posted is solved

Comment: No but what I want is to count how many balls I have on one side of wall and the other side of wall, but what it does is just count up to 200 and crashes. I want to play with the wall open and close it and have more balls on one side than the other and I would have the count of how many balls are in one side of wall and other side of wall. If im making sense?

Comment: well all your dots are in the same array and you add them with the same method so you cant really count only one side. the only thing I can think of is checking the location of each dot and see if its to the left of the middle of the screen or to the right of it.

Comment: Yes I have in my Dot class where my dots are located, so yeah I am using location. Would it be helpful if post the other class?

Comment: I strongly recommend that first you try something simpler then what you are trying to do now. it seems to me that you lack the proper knowledge to attempt something like this, read a book on java or find a good learning site. don't try sticking together a bunch of code that you found on the web.

Comment: Excuse me who said that I am butting a bunch of code together? I did this whole thing, but there is one thing that I am not really a fan of and want help on.

Comment: I wasn't trying to offend you and i'm sorry if I did. Its just that if you can't find a way to check if the dots are on the left or right you should take a step back and see why is it so difficult maybe there is a better way to arrange your program.

Comment: Like I said I have the other class that does that should I post it?

Comment: Just create 2 counters left and right then iterate through your Dots array and check the X location of each Dot if X is less than frame width/2 increment the left counter otherwise the right.

Comment: And where is that supposed to be in this main program or in my Dot class?

Comment: You will need the counters to draw ther values so I suggest you do it in your main since your paint method is there.

Comment: Besides your Dot class probably represents only one Dot so you can't really iterate though all the Dots in it unless you have a pointer to your Dots array from main or main it self

Comment: Yes I have a pointer to main class from my Dot class

Comment: I am afraid that I dont get what your explanation, If it is in a form of a code it could make so much sense.

Comment: yes i saw the `Dot.theDotChaser = this;` but still since your paint method is in the DotChaser class do it in DotChaser.

Comment: PS: try to avoid the use of static as much as possible

Comment: tell you what ill write the whole thing for you if it will help you learn. give me your mail or something and ill send you the source code tomorrow.

Comment: ok ill send you the code tomorrow